# How to reset JDPA environmental variable on UBUNTU 18.04?

Tags: tomcat

I set Tomcat debug mode port in Intellij. However, because could not see it running I set it again from the terminal. Since then I cannot run debug at all.

I tried to solve by deleting my settings form environment file but actually, I could find no such commands in the file.

The lines I entered in the terminal were

```
export JPDA_ADDRESS=8000

export JPDA_TRANSPORT=dt_socket
```

Please, let me know how to reset to default settings?

Comment: I am sorry just realised that I misstyped my title. I meant variable instead of varial.

Comment: Note that you can [edit] your post and fix that

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables in Linux are not permanent. So:

- When a process sets or changes an environment variable, this change affects only this process and its subsequently created children
- Changes don't propagate retroactively, ie. if a change is made after a child process is spawned, the child will retain the old value
- Changes don't affect ancestors and unrelated processes

So to reset the variable, simply close the terminal and processes launched from that terminal or open a new one. Changing that variable in a single terminal could only affect that terminal and processes it spawned.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought so, too. However still receive the below message at starting debug.
Error running 'debug': Unable to open debugger port (localhost:8000): java.net.ConnectException "Kapcsolat elutasítva (Connection refused)"

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought so, too. However still receive the below message at starting debug in IntelliJ.
Error running 'debug': Unable to open debugger port (localhost:8000): java.net.ConnectException "Kapcsolat elutasítva (Connection refused)"

Comment: That's a separate problem, maybe better suited for Stack Overflow. I don't know how this debugger is supposed to work, but it sounds like the debugger should be running a server on port 8000. Your client tries to connect to that port, but the connection is refused. Maybe the debugger is not running or is using a different port? Are you maybe running this in a container or VM of some sort (Docker maybe), so the server is not on the same host? Anyway, if you want to follow on this problem, you should ask a new question.